# Get percentage amount of Stockfish usage

Tags: stockfish

Is it a way to paste FEN from a game and see how many of those moves Stockfish would recommend doing? If the percentage is high, the person has most likely been using it. Is there a way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question related to the general topic of using of a chess engine to cheat. There has been quite a lot of research on this by people like [Kenneth Reagan](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/chess/). I have also done some research in this area and [made some open source tools available](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/chessplag/) that will allow you to generate statistics on move matching with engine choices. I think these would do what you are asking.

Comment: Do you have any specific papers you want to recommend? About the statistics?

Comment: This is [a good starting point] (http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/chess/fidelity/) for Kenneth Reagan's work and a useful [discussion of statistical significance] (http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/chess/fidelity/Golfers.html). His [report to the ACP board members] (http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/chess/fidelity/ACPcover-and-report.pdf) is also useful for understanding the statistics in practice. [My own paper] (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cose.2014.10.002) covers some of the risks with statistical issues. If anyone wishes to contact me personally I can send them a copy as it is paywalled.